# Predicting a variable from categorical time series input that is unevenly spaced and of unequal length

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, references, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I would like to predict the value of some variable $x$ at time $t$ based on the evolution of the state of the system in the time interval $(t-T,t]$. The system can be in any number of states in the interval $(t-T,t]$ and the time spent in each state is variable.

Consider the following simple example. A machine can be in the following states: producing, idle or being cleaned. The quality of products is denoted by $x$. We are interested in the quality of the product finished at time $t$. Let's fix $T = 10$ minutes. The machine has been producing from $(t-10,t-5]$, idle from $(t-5,t-2.21]$, being cleaned from $(t-2.21, t-1]$ and finally producing from $t-1$ onwards.

I'm not sure where to start with creating a prediction model that can handle such strange time series as input. Should I instead created a fixed-length time series where I sample the state every second? Does anyone have references that I could look into?

Comment: A Markov model with previous state and time spent in previous state as predictors? Is a transition from any state to any other possible?

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Ideally, I'd like to include the full 10 minute history in the prediction of $x$ at time $t$. Would that fit in that Markov model framework?

Comment: You can have additional parameters for previous previous state (and another one for time spent in that state) as long as you have the degrees of freedom, but that may not handle the entire history very well if there's large variability (e.g. one machine has just one state change vs. many for another); one of the big factors is the number of previous states you include aka. the order of the model. The underlying assumption in Markov is that the next state only depends on the previous one(s) that were included in the model.